# matching and grouping string using XSLT regex analyze-string

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am making use of XSLT 2.0 to find the matching substring based on the regular expressions

my XSLT function looks like below

```
<xsl:function name="util:getSource">
    <xsl:variable name="dynamic" select="'Allergy Adverse Event Type 2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.12.3221.6.2'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($dynamic) &gt; 1 and matches($dynamic,'[a-zA-Z\s]*')">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$dynamic" regex="[a-zA-Z\s]*">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

I would like to find **"Allergy Adverse Event Type"** from my input string **"'Allergy Adverse Event Type 2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.12.3221.6.2'"** based on the regular expression **[a-zA-Z\s]***; when i am executing above function always i am receiving "XTDE1150: Regular expression matches the empty string". what is wrong with the regular expression; can I have the suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string):

> [ERR XTDE1150] It is a non-recoverable dynamic error if the effective
>   value of the regex attribute is a regular expression that matches a
>   zero-length string

Just change your regex to `[a-zA-Z\s]+` and you should be ok.